# Why is Google Speech API so much worse than the built-in speech recognition

Tags: speech-recognition, google-speech-api

I am using the Google Speech API on Android to enable speech-to-text in my Android app. However, I noticed that the recognition is much worse compared to Google Assistant or the built-in "Hey Google" services.

Are those using another API or is it the same one, and what could be the reason that the quality differs so much.

As an example, when I say "Smitten Ice Cream" (a place in SF, CA), Google Maps understands the speech right away whereas my app does not after 5 attempts. Is there maybe a way to add context to the Speech API that I'm trying to transcribe a location?

Comment: are you using google speech api with android sdk ?

Comment: @DrNio yes, I am

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Improve Android speech recognition with additional context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29139275/improve-android-speech-recognition-with-additional-context)

Comment: No, because I also want to understand the difference why the built-in services work better

Answer (score 4):

This answer is based on an assumption, from years of using the inbuilt Google [SpeechRecognizer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer.html) for my [applications](https://github.com/brandall76/Saiy-PS).

I have had many, many reports that when users first start using my applications, the voice recognition is nowhere near as accurate as they are used to with Google Now/Assistant - even though it seemingly, is the same 'service' on their device.

The assumption is, that when you place your [package name](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognizerIntent.html#EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE) in the Intent details:

```
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE, getPackageName());
```

Google will start a new 'voice model' for this package, unless one already exists. As stated in the documentation, if you omit this - Google is likely to add this regardless.

This is actually a sensible approach. If your application is focused on medical terms, you would not want the results to be biased against such terms - which any existing model, most likely would be.

I've found after a short period of usage, the accuracy increases greatly.

There is another potential issue, due to a long standing bug - If the recognition results continue to be way off, you'll need to uninstall the Google App that provides the [RecognitionService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognitionService.html), remove all files etc and reinstall. This is an instant fix for those whose accuracy is inexplicably terrible.

A paragraph, very similar to the above, appears in my app Troubleshooting section to try and help users understand. I've not had a situation where the recognition accuracy didn't improve.

Not a solution for you, but I hope confirming your experience will help.

Comment: Did I understand this correctly - there are 2 different ways to use speech in Android? The Google Speech API of the Google Cloud and the built-in SpeechRecognizer?

Comment: @phoebus there are two different native ways. The `SpeechRecognizer` and the `RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH` Intent. Google's Cloud Speech API is an external service, that you can use via a number of methods, such as a RESTful Service. It is not free. There are many other Speech Recognition providers who offer paid RESTful APIs.

Comment: @brandall do `RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH` also uses google's cloud speech API under the hood?